# Extract the Characters from the Blurred image

Tags: image, ocr

I want extract the characters from the blurred image that is present below: 
I used basic pytesseract code and tried applying adaptive threshold filter but I was not able to get the output fully correct...

```py
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

img  = cv2.imread('M.jpeg')
img=cv2.resize(img,(400,200))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15,7)

cv2.imshow('f',thresh)

text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

I want the characters or at least right side of the information to be printed correctly. [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xamTo.png)